# How do I create files in an AppFolder in OneDrive for Business using the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a custom Azure AD App, "Microsoft Graph Test", with the `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` delegated permission. Based on the [Graph API Reference for special folders](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/05450e72d906cc68b69dbb7262a773e0d4f11b12/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_special.md), I believe that `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/special/approot` should be creating an AppFolder for my app if it doesn't already exist. However, when I execute the request (using the Graph Explorer from the [Excel Graph Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-Excel-REST-ToDo)) I see a `401 Unauthorized` response.

If I give the app the `Files.ReadWrite` scope, the same command results in a `200 OK` result that creates a folder in OneDrive for Business at `Apps/Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService`.

Based on this, I have two questions:

1. What Microsoft Graph operations does the `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` scope enable?
2. How can I create and access an AppFolder using the `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` scope is invalid and shouldn't be used. I've opened a bug to get the documentation fixed to remove this reference. Right now through Microsoft Graph you need to request Files.ReadWrite permissions to use app folders.

I'm investigating the issue where the app folder name was created as AgregatorService instead of your app's actual name.

Comment: "Right now through Microsoft Graph you need to request Files.ReadWrite permissions to use app folders."

What are the plans for the future?

Comment: We definitely want to support this in the future. However, the permissions model in SharePoint doesn't lend itself to easily adding this feature. We're working on the necessary changes to the service to support this feature and will ship it as soon as we have a secure solution.

Comment: Ryan, any news about AppFolder?

Comment: 3.5 years later, Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder still only works for personal accounts...

Comment: There is a feature request here https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39861952-make-files-readwrite-appfolder-scope-available-for , could be worth putting a vote in...